# Не устанавливается pyTelegramBotAPI pip последней версии, cmd запускал от администратора. Нечего не помогало

Tags: python, telebot

```
PS C:\Users\'USER'> pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
Collecting pyTelegramBotAPI
  Using cached pyTelegramBotAPI-4.6.0.tar.gz (160 kB)
  ERROR: Error [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе while executing command python setup.py egg_info
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе
Check the permissions.
```

Comment: Python у вас не в Program Files случайно установлен?

Comment: В Program Files, а это критично?

Comment: Для установки пакетов python их обычно устанавливает в папку python, а для записи в Program Files нужны права администратора. Он по идее должен понимать, что у него прав нет, и устанавливать пакеты в папку пользователя, но видимо не всегда это срабатывает. Поэтому лучше Python ставить или в папку пользователя, ли в папку в корне диска, например, c:/python, и или вообще в любое место, где не требуются прав администратора для записи.

Comment: Переместил в папку пользователя. Скачалось. При запуске пишет can't open file 'путь': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Приведите полный текст ошибки.

Comment: C:\Users\User"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.10.exe: can't open file 'c:\\Users\\User\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\teleBot\\main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: У вас после User кавычка стоит - это так и должно быть?

Comment: Случайно написал. Вот так должно быть
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.10.exe: can't open file 'c:\\Users\\User\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\telegBot\\main.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Как запускаете хоть? Если зайти через cmd в папку вашего проекта и выполнить `python main.py`, то запустится?

Comment: Нет, не запускается

Comment: запускал и через cmd и через Visual studio code, PyCharm

Comment: А что происходит? прямо делали `cd c:\Users\User\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\telegBot` (или как там у вас на самом деле папка называется) потом `python main.py`, и писало, что файл не существует? Вообще, попробуйте выпилить python установленный через магазин, и скачайте с python.org